# Parsing Relaxed Dates in Python

Tags: python, nlp

Is there any package (like Natty in Java) in python that is able to parse a relaxed date such as:

"Third day of September, 1988"

I tried using parsedatetime, and I get the correct month and year, but not the correct day.

```
>>>>import parsedatetime  
>>>>cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
>>>>cal.parse("Third day of September, 1988")
((1988, 9, 1, 14, 2, 15, 2, 253, 1), 1)
```

Am I using the module wrong? If not, is there an alternative package I can use that can get the correct resi;t?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is any direct replacement for Natty on Python. As you found `parsedatetime` is close but not quite what you want. `parsedatetime` will accept `"3rd September, 1988"` . It doesn't like `day of`.

If you want Natty and you are willing to run Java from Python then you may want to see this [article](http://baojie.org/blog/2014/06/16/call-java-from-python/) about different ways of doing that.